# Copy of object by passing as method parameter

Tags: java, oop, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, objectinstantiation

I am a bit confused about Java's pass by reference/values in method parameters.

I have a constructor in an `OuterObject` class:

```
private InnerObject io;
public OuterObject(InnerObject io){ 
    this.io = io;
}

public InnerObject getInnerObject(){
    return this.io;
}
```

If I pass an `OuterObject` into a copy method like this:

```
InnerObject io = new InnerObject();
OuterObject o = new OuterObject(io);    
anotherClass.getCopyOf(o);
```

and in another class:

```
public static OuterObject getCopyOf(InnerObject o){
    return new OuterObject(o.getInnerObject());
}
```

As you can see I create the `OuterObject` with the `InnerObject` as a parameter. Now I would like to know:

Do I get two new Objects from the return statement, 
or is it only a new `OuterObject` copy but same reference to the existing `InnerObject`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store objects in variables or parameters you always store the reference. The object is never copied. Only primitive types, such as `int` or `boolean` are copied.

If you want to create copies of objects you should look into object cloning using the `java.lang.Cloneable` interface and the `Clone` method or a copy constructor. What you choose is but a matter of preference. I usually perfer copy constructors as they show more clearly what is happening. At least for me.

Also your line `return new Object(o.getInnerObject());` will not compile. But I guess you wanted to write `OuterObject` instead of `Object` here.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `new Object(o.getInnerObject())` won't compile, since `Object` doesn't have a matching constructor.

Assuming you replace it with `new OuterObject (o.getInnerObject());`, the new instance of `OuterObject` would contain the same instance of `InnerObject` that `o` contains, since the constructor of `OuterObject` doesn't create a copy of the `InnerObject` instance passed to it.

Comment: @MidgarZolom the getter doesn't change my answer (had the getter returned a copy of this.io, the answer would have changed).

Answer (score 2):

You get as much objects as you have created with the `new` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Your codes have compiling errors in this line:
return new Object(o.getInnerObject());
o is an instance of Object.So, it cannot have a method like getInnerObject();
Also,Object does't have a constructor like Object(InnerObject).
So,change

```html
public static Object getCopyOf(Object o){
    return new Object(o.getInnerObject());
}
```

into

```html
public static OuterObject getCopyOf(Object o){
    return new OuterObject(((OuterObject)o).getInnerObject());
}
```

We can answer your question now.
'new' will always create an new object in heap memory,but the two outerObjects have the same innerObject reference.

Comment: yes i am a bit under time pressure, i made some errors on typing here, i hope i fixed them all, but the essence of my question should be clear and is already answered